# How to get CPU's model number like Core i7-860 on Windows?

Tags: windows, cpu

There are many kinds of i7 CPU models as follows:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors#Desktop_processors

How to know which version I am using on Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CPU-Z (freeware)](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) can give you this information.

Comment: it might be worth noting that cpu-z has a no-interface mode that dumps results to a textfile (if the OP was interested in consuming this information programmatically)

Answer (score 13):

Open up "System Information" by

```
Start Menu > Accessories > System Tools > System Information
```

Then once in "System Information" open:

```
System Information > System Summary
```

On the right will be the "Processor", this will give you the full description of your CPU.

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>  +  <kbd>R</kbd>  will open the run command

Type `CMD` and press

Type `wmic CPU get NAME` and  <kbd>enter</kbd>

For me it gives :

```
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU  **920**  @ 2.67GHz
```

Where the 920 is what I think your looking for...
If its not, if you just type `wmic CPU` and press  <kbd>enter</kbd>  it will give you all the information about the processor in a hard to read fashion...
But then you can type `wmic CPU get (whatever entry interests you)` to get just that one.
Good Luck

Answer (score 7):

You can check the `Name` Property of the [`Win32_Processor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class

Try this C# sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string ComputerName = "localhost";
                ManagementScope Scope;                
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);
                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Name FROM Win32_Processor");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);
                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}",WmiObject["Name"]);                     
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not a C# programmer :'(

Comment: You can access the WMI using many languages like c#, c++, delphi, python, vbscript, java and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is just to open "Start" -> "Computer" -> "System Properties"

Answer (score 2):

open Windows PowerShell, type the following:

```
 > gwmi -query "SELECT Name FROM Win32_Processor"

Name       : Intel (R) Cor.....i7-2670QM CPU @2.20GHz
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'wmic' tool on the shell:

```
>wmic cpu get name
Name
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
```

Please note: In some relatively rare case you might see access restrictions to those value.