# Developing Android Apps - Can't use any android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I searched for days to find a way to start programming android applications however I failed every single try.

First I installed Android Studio on my **Windows 7 computer**, everything went fine.
After installation I tried to start a project and debug it and appeared my first error that you can see in the link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9BlJ.png

Then I searched here on stackoverflow and I searched on every single website that is related to this error. What did I learn?

- I need to install an Intel package on SDK Manager
- I also need to install an executable present on appdata android studio directory
- I MUST disable or uninstall hyper-v to install the exe file I spoke on the step before

I searched on how to get this hyper-v out of my computer and I found many ways however when I tried this ways and then tried to install the exe file, it shows this message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQjON.png

I don't know if my computer has hyper-v, the only way I can't do is going to my BIOS and disable it because I don't know the keys I need to press to show my computer BIOS (on the startup it doesn't show any label about the BIOS keys).

My computer model is **Sony VAIO VGN-NS11Z_S**, if someone knows the BIOS keys please tell me.

I can't use the emulator to try out my app so I gave up from Android Studio and I started with Eclipse and the ADT Plugin.
My problem is still the same, I don't if it is because hyper-v but the android emulator don't work.
Everything is fine but I can't test my app so I can't develop them too...

I really appreciate any help, I want to create Android apps so much, please give me an alternative or a way to fix my problems.

Thank you

Comment: Add the error text to your question - those do look like some very interesting errors (screenshots), but we shouldn't have to click a link to get the essential info.

Comment: Can you confirm your CPU - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10595355/295004, I fear that it is a Core2Duo that doesn't have VT-x and therefore can't run HAXM

Comment: My CPU is Intel Core2Duo...

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). It also needs some sort of hardware acceleration but give it a try.
2. It can't be that hard to find out the keystroke for your BIOS (EDIT: okay, it can be obviously for some devices). Just google for "your mainboard manufacturer + bios". I found [this](https://community.sony.com/t5/VAIO-Upgrade-Backup-Recovery/How-can-I-enter-bios-on-my-vaio-I-want-to-boot-from-the-cd-drive/td-p/60063) thread, one post even mentions Hyper-V.
3. Android Studio and Eclipse have nothing to do with the Emulator. The Emulator is part of the Android SDK which is identical for both IDEs. Throw away Eclipse (at least for Android).
4. As a last resort, run the Emulator with an ARM image instead of the i86 one, I think it runs without HAX and without hardware acceleration. It's damn slow though.
5. If you want to do serious Android development, there's no way around a real device. There's plenty of cheap options. That's just a little heads up though, I understand though that you still need an emulator for development.

Comment: How can I switch from i86 to ARM?

Comment: Select the x86 image when creating a new virtual device (you'll probably have to download the image first): http://de.tinypic.com/r/20aqatw/8

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting link on Sony's website about a BIOS update that may help (disclaimer: BIOS updates are not guaranteed to be safe, install at your own risk and make sure it's the exact right one for your computer):

http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/content/cnt-dwnl/prd-comp/EP0000208387_4486/VGN-NS11Z

But also within that link it mentions to press F2 to get into your BIOS. Does that work for you?